# Grocery store sales data in the US

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for a source that would provide sales data for grocery stores in the US or companies that provide such data.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following on Quandl:

[US Census Bureau database](https://www.quandl.com/data/USCENSUS) - search for "grocery sales" within the database and you'll see data for retail grocery sales

[Federal Reserve Economic Data database](https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED) - search for "grocery sales" within the database and you'll see data for sales by grocery chain stores

[US Industry Aggregates](https://www.quandl.com/data/EA1) - search for "grocery sales" within the database and you'll see grocery stores aggregate sales, aggregate cash flow etc (this is a premium database)

Hope this helps!

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know if Quandl have sales data for individual grocery stores in the US? Or is it just aggregated sales data?

Comment: Hi @WillCK , the databases I mentioned have aggregated sales data. But, if you want to see individual grocery stores sales, you might actually want to check out our Zacks Sales Surprises database (premium): https://www.quandl.com/data/ZSS. It covers sales data for 5000+ companies, some of which are grocery stores like Safeway or Kroger. For a full list of companies covered, download the ticker list here: https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/ZSS/codes